# SQL Server 2005 query syntax error: "The column 'id_ctrc' was specified multiple times for 'inner_tbl'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
WITH outer_tbl
AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY inner_tbl.ctrc_data DESC ) AS KOHANA_DB_ROWNUM, * 
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM rkm_sac_ctrc 
      INNER JOIN rkm_sac_nf ON (rkm_sac_ctrc.id_ctrc = rkm_sac_nf.id_ctrc) 
    WHERE rkm_sac_ctrc.pag_cnpj = '46.344.354/0005-88' 
    AND rkm_sac_nf.nf_numero = '2023'
  ) AS inner_tbl
) 
SELECT * FROM outer_tbl WHERE KOHANA_DB_ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 AND 15
```

The error is:

> The column 'id_ctrc' was specified multiple times for 'inner_tbl'.
>
> The column 'id_ctrc' was specified multiple times for 'outer_tbl'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those are great table/column names. Much fun working with them?

Comment: @Mitch - Are you saying that don't understand what `rkm_sac_ctrc` is? *snigger* EVERYONE knows what it means!

Comment: @Mitch - It's a non-English language, those may in fact be very appropriate and descriptive names.

Comment: @Nick Craver: assuming non-english: they are still horrible table names

Comment: This is a customer database... I can't rename anything...

Comment: what is the schema for the views rkm_sac_ctrc and rkm_sac_nf? Is that the default schema for the current user you are using to execute the query?

Comment: @Álvaro Guimarães: I was assuming that was the case. Apologies for my flippance: it comes of 'working' with SAP!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use select *. You need to have specific column names for each column and you havea  join hence two columns with the same name.  You should never be using select * in any event but especially when you have a  join becasue you are returning extra unneded information.

Answer (score 1):

try to include the schema of the table

Comment: virtual -1. This is not an answer. This must be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely reason is the schema - your code will most likely run against **dbo**. Your views are possibly in another schema.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you are running this in the proper database? run this query to check:

```
select
    TABLE_CATALOG+'.'+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views 
    where TABLE_NAME='rkm_sac_ctrc'
```

if it is returned, use schema name given in the results

Comment: I was doing it in the wrong schema... question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

By default in Management Studio, your SQL may be running against the Master database.

That would be why it can't find your tables, which are in another database.

**Try adding a USE statement** before your SQL, such as `USE DatabaseName`.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then you may need to prefix the table names with the shema and/or owner name. Quite often, that is `dbo`. But it could be something else. In Management Studio, you can see that easily enough in the Object Explorer pane. Look at the view names there.